# How to concatenate array with apostrophy and comma in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, concatenation

I cannot figure out the best approach to my problem.  I wish to concatenate a list of numbers into an array, and affix '', to it.

For example:

'1234','5678','...

I managed to get it to work with commas by doing:

```
var radio_comma = document.getElementById("optionsRadios1").value;

if (document.getElementById("optionsRadios1").checked) {
        sku_output = txtArray.join(radio_comma);
}
```

I can't figure out how to ammend it with 'number',

I did attempt this with

```
sku_output = radio_singlequote.concat(x, radio_singlequote, radio_comma);
```

however it will output '123,123,123,123,123'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sku_output = "'" + txtArray.join("','") + "'"` should give the output you search.

You could make an `Array` extension for it

```
Array.prototype.toSingleQuotedString = function () {
  return "'" + this.join("','") + "'";
}
//=> sku_output = txtArray.toSingleQuotedString();
```

Another angle is using `Array.map` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```
sku_output = txtArray.map( function (a) { return "'"+a+"'"; } ).join(',');
```

Comment: Hi Dave, glad I could be of assistance